# Batchconverting files to webp with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have this code currently that converts my .png into .webp files, but the ending of the files stays at .png.
How do I have to adjust $file in the -o option to be able to be filename.webp?

```
foreach ($file in get-ChildItem *.png) {
    #Echo $file
    cwebp -q 100 $file -o $file
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference the `BaseName` property, then add the new extension:

```
cwebp -q 100 $file.Name -o ($file.Basename + '.webp')
```